# Django Rest Framework Send Data to View Without Serializer

Tags: django, email, post, django-rest-framework

I have a `Magic` model in my application. I need the user who is attached to this model to go to their email address to verify something before they can access the information. This should happen over a RESTful API. The problem is, the user should not necessarily be logged in to access this feature (for design decisions I had no control over).

I have implemented the logic for generating the necessary information and sending the email (only if such an email is registered), authentication once the emailed information is accessed, etc.

My question: How do I implement a view that takes a user email in the body (or url)?

**Approach 1**: create a url `/magic_api/v1/tdbverification/(?P<email>[\w.@]+)/` and extract the email address and send the email.

**Problem with 1**: I cannot seem to extract the email *and* I need to return a json object without having a serializer

**Approach 2**: Create a view that takes body: `{"email": "<email@here.com>"}`

**Problem with 2**: This requires a serializer without a model (as this view is just for sending the email, it does not change model objects). I tried working with a `serializers.Serializer` class but could not figure out how to incorporate the email sending logic.

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have to shout this out, do not include sensitive user data (like even emails) in the url.  Never, never.  It is much easier for bad actors to intercept this data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why you always need a serializer! You can write a view without using a serializer. Example

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Test(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        ...  your logic ...
        return Response(...)
```

Comment: `from rest_framework_jwt.views import APIView` or `from rest_framework.generics import APIView`?

Comment: rest framework generic not contains APIView. from rest_framework.views import APIView

Comment: I don't think this will result in a good view inside the API root and you'll have to do your own validation.   Including a basic serializer is not very hard, and will allow all the DRF features to work properly.

Comment: Here is an example of using a serializer to validate the data and then overide save method to send mail: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly